# How to convert Variable to keras Layer

Tags: python, keras

The output is

```
tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(10, 15, 9488) dtype=float32_ref
```

I want to convert it to keras layer.

```
input_output = Input(shape=(10,512))
model = Model(input_output, output)
```

Is there any way to do that?

currently, the error is

```
Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras Layer (thus holding past layer metadata).
Found:
tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=(10, 15, 9488) dtype=float32_ref
```

=============================================
I tried to use Lambda, but got the error below: 
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer`
 
(thus holding past layer metadata). 
Found: keras.layers.core.Lambda object at 0x7fad52faf550

Here is what I did:

```
def convert_tensor(self, outputs):
    return outputs

input_result = Input(shape=(int(outputs.shape[0]), int(outputs.shape[1]),int(outputs.shape[2])))
outputs = Lambda(self.convert_tensor(outputs), output_shape=(10, 15, 9488))
model = Model(input_result, outputs)
```

Comment: You can't "convert" this, but you can use a Lambda layer to transform the code that performs the computation into a Layer that Keras can use. There is no workaround for this, other than  coding a full Keras layer.

Comment: Thank you,  Matias. I tried to use Lambda, but got another error. I am not familiar with that. I just updated the question. Could you please provide more help?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using the Lambda layer correctly, it should be like this:

```
input_result = Input(shape=(int(outputs.shape[0]), int(outputs.shape[1]),int(outputs.shape[2])))
outputs = Lambda(self.convert_tensor, output_shape=(10, 15, 9488))(input_result)
model = Model(input_result, outputs)
```

You have to pass the function to the lambda, not a function call, and then you "call" the lambda with the appropriate input.

Comment: Great. Thank you,  Matias. I will have a try.

Comment: This will not make the tensor trainable.

Comment: @mathtick For that you need to make a full Keras layer.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks, that is the only way I've got that to work: create a full custom keras layer with a spoofed kernal that is then multiplied by zero. I just don't get how this can be missing from keras. Seems like a simple Bias layer would solve it ... and some way that doesn't introduce n weights that then do not get used.